# Create array of objects based on length; each object has a property with the index + 1 as its value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to improve my ugly code to something more clean and simple.
How can I shorten this code?

```js
if (this.foo < 2) {
  return (this.result = [ { year: 1 } ]);
}
if (this.foo < 3) {
  return (this.result = [ { year: 1 }, { year: 2 } ]);
}
if (this.foo < 4) {
  return (this.result = [ { year: 1 }, { year: 2 }, { year: 3 } ]);
}
if (this.foo < 5) {
  return (this.result = [ { year: 1 }, { year: 2 }, { year: 3 }, { year: 4 } ]);
}
if (this.foo < 6) {
  return (this.result = [ { year: 1 }, { year: 2 }, { year: 3 }, { year: 4 }, { year: 5 } ]);
}
```

Comment: The task can be done by a for-loop,

Comment: `return this.result = Array.from({ length: Math.floor(this.foo) }, (_, index) => ({ year: index + 1 }));`? Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process objects and arrays](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Comment: It would be better if you described your question. For example _"I want to produce an array of length `this.foo - 1` filled with objects of `{year: n}` where `n` is the 1-based index of the object in the array"_. Sound about right?

Comment: @Phil thank you for your specific comments!! My English is not good so it is little difficult to specify what I want TT

Comment: @SebastianSimon 5 star for using `Array.form`

Comment: [Related](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+create+array+with+n+objects+with+index+as+value): [How to create an array containing 1…N](/q/3746725/4642212).

Comment: @EllenMinaKim all good, a description of a problem usually makes it easier to solve and sometimes you even solve it yourself while trying to explain it (see [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). Looks like you got some good answers already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you’ve shown is equivalent to this (except this goes beyond five elements, but also beyond one in the other direction):

```js
return this.result = Array.from({
  length: Math.floor(this.foo)
}, (_value, index) => ({
  year: index + 1
}));
```

This assumes that this statement is inside a function (otherwise, `return` wouldn’t work).

A more reasonable length may be `Math.max(0, Math.min(2 ** 32 - 1, Math.floor(this.foo)))` which clamps<sup>1</sup> the length to at least 0 and at most 2<sup>32</sup> − 1, the [maximum Array length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

If you want to always have at least one element in your array, then use `Math.max(1,`…`)` instead.

Returning an assignment (i.e. `return this.result =`…`;`) is [frowned upon](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign).
The best practice is to separate these statements<sup>2</sup>:

```js
this.result = Array.from({
  length: Math.max(0, Math.min(2 ** 32 - 1, Math.floor(this.foo)))
}, (_value, index) => ({
  year: index + 1
}));

return this.result;
```

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is used with both arguments: the first one is the “array-like” object `{ length: Math.max(0, Math.min(2 ** 32 - 1, Math.floor(this.foo))) }` which gets converted to a proper `Array` object.
In this case, an array with a length of `Math.floor(this.foo)` is initialized (clamped to the range of possible Array lengths).
The second argument maps each value at a certain `index` to an object with the `year` property with the value `index + 1`.
`_value` isn’t used (it’s `undefined` anyway).

The advantage to use `Array.from(`*array-like*`,`*mapping-function*`)` over e.g. `.fill().map(`…`)` is that only a single array is created in memory.
`Array(`…`).fill().map(`…`)` creates *two* new arrays: the first one at `Array(`…`).fill()`, the second one at `.map(`…`)`.
Therefore, the `Array.from` approach is more memory-efficient.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Maybe soon we’ll finally get a [`Math.clamp`](https://github.com/rwaldron/proposal-math-extensions) method…

<sup>2</sup>: Technically, this would be equivalent.
If `this.result` is a getter / setter, there may be an observable difference.

```js
const result = Array.from({
    length: Math.max(0, Math.min(2 ** 32 - 1, Math.floor(this.foo)))
  }, (_value, index) => ({
    year: index + 1
  }));

this.result = result;

return result;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Math.max(1, ...`?

Comment: @Phil Depends on the exact requirements. I’ve included a paragraph that explains this.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks, I am writing the codes myself and learning them!!!

Comment: @SebastianSimon It doesn't look like `Array(n)` takes space `n` immediately. Shoudn't it be two steps?

Comment: @zmag You’re kind of right: `Array(n)` creates a new array, nonetheless, but I forgot that `.fill` _mutates_ the array instead of creating a new array.

Answer (score 7):

Create an array with `Array`, and use `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
function func(foo) {
  return Array(foo).fill().map((f, i) => ({ year: i + 1 }));
}

console.log(func(1));
console.log(func(3));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this oneliner

```
let x=3;
let result = [ ...Array(x).keys() ].map(item=> {return{"year":item}});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [];

for(let i = 1; i<this.foo;i++){ 
    arr.push({ 'year':i}) 
};

console.log(arr);
```